# InDesign: Adjust object position when shuffling left/right pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I'm working on a document (some 120 pages, so I'd like to avoid the need to adjust each page manually) with texts and photos. It is sort of a catalogue with each page having independent text, two photos and some infobox. I've created a 2-page master with the basic layout which looks like this:

[image: Layout]

But the problem is that when I add a page *before* those already created (which has to be done, because there will certainly be some last-minute additions or changes in page order), the left pages become right and vice versa, but then all the master page items that have been locally overridden stay where they are relatively to the page, which of course breaks the layout (e.g. the part of the photo that was in the bleed area ends up at the spine overflowing to the other page in the spread).

Is there any way to align the objects relatively to spine and inside/outside edge of the page, so they adjust when the pages shuffle? Or to automatically follow the position of master page items even when they are overridden?

I know this works when an object is aligned to margin guides. But as you see, I need to align several objects in different parts of the page.

Thanks, I'll appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a possible solution: I put all the objects that should adjust their position into a blank text frame as anchored objects, and then in *Anchored Object Options* set their position as **Custom** and **Relative to Spine** with appropriate X and Y Offset from Page Edge.

Now when the page changes left/right, the anchored objects adjust their position as expected, relative to spine.

I don't know if it is the best way to do it, but it seems to accomplish what I need.